# how to access the object using index

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const data= {
  fruit: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  vegies: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  soaps: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  softdrinks: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  
}
```

In javascript how to access fruits number using index something like data[0].number plaese help me or else suggest me better kind of storing these type of data to access it with index

Comment: Does it have to be by index or can it be by name? The `data` variable refers to an object with properties identified by name. So you can access an item using `data.fruit.number` or `data["fruit"].number`. More information about what you're trying to accomplish would be helpful.

Comment: no @JackA. i want to do it with index because i want to use this inside a map function so that i can use it like data[index].number

Comment: ```map``` is used to transform one array to a different array. So you have to convert your data structure to an array. Perhaps ```data = [ { category: 'fruits', number: ... }, {category: 'veggies', number: ...} ... ];``` is what you want. This will allow you to use ```map```, but also find a particular category by using ```data.filter((c)=>c.category==='fruits')```

Comment: Could you give a reasonably complete example of how you'd like to use it in a `map` function in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript array for this. As only array can help you out for index based access

Comment: can you please give me some sample data how to store this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it with index it must be an Array.

```js
const data = [{
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },

]

console.log(data[0].number)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data= {
  fruit: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  vegies: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  soaps: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  softdrinks: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  
}

data[Object.keys(data)[0]] 

/* 
  Output will be

fruit: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  }
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this I guess:

```js
const data= {
  fruit: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  vegies: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  soaps: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  softdrinks: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  }
}
const ar = Object.values(data)
console.log(ar[0].number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remain using Object instead of Array. Get keys from the data, and when you have array of keys, you can iterate through keys with `.map` over the data using [property accessors in javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors)

```
const data= {
  fruit: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  vegies: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  soaps: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  softdrinks: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  
}
const keys = Object.keys(data);
keys.forEach(key => {console.log( key, data[key]);})
```

```js
    const data= {
  fruit: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  vegies: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  soaps: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  },
  softdrinks: {
    number: null,
    type: null,
    sold: null
  }, 
}
const keys = Object.keys(data);
console.log('keys', keys);
keys.forEach(key => {console.log( key, data[key]);})
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way would probably be to use an array, even though the solutions of the other people of course works.

```js
class item {
    constructor(name, number=null, type=null, sold=null) {
        this.name = name
        this.number = number;
        this.type = type;
        this.sold = sold;
    }
}

data = ["fruit", "veggies", "soaps", "softdrinks"].map(it => new item(it));

console.log(data[0]);
```